# Find global variable at runtime in memory based on PE image base

Tags: c, assembly, memory, portable-executable

I'm trying to find a global variable of a PE image at runtime in memory (programatically). When looking at the initialization of the variable in IDA (disassembler), it looks like this:

ASM:

```
mov     cs:qword_ED10, rdx
```

Pseudo C:

```
qword_ED10 = (__int64)SystemTable;
```

I assumed that the variable would be stored at offset ED10 relative to the PE base address, but this seems to be wrong. How can I find this global value at runtime based on the image base address of the PE?

Comment: One of the sections of a PE file is initialized data. The offset is likely relative to the start of that section.

Comment: I would look at the actual machine code and the relocation entries if any. IDA is sometimes trying too hard to be helpful and hides the details from you... It may for example be a rip-relative address (hence the `cs` prefix maybe?)

Comment: I did that now, thanks. The disassembly looks like this: `mov qword ptr [rip + 0xe902], rdx`. But what is the value of RIP when execution is transfered to the entry point of the PE? (initializing the variable is the first thing the PE does)

Comment: That depends on ASLR. You should find the offset of this instruction from its section base, then check what the loader picked at runtime. Finally add the offset (adjusted for instruction length).

Comment: Thank you. However, there is no ASLR in my case (UEFI execution environment).

Comment: Well then look at the base address of the code section which should then be static.

Comment: The problem has been solved. I was looking at the unmapped version of the PE the whole time and not the one that was actually executing that was located somewhere else... suddenly the offset ED10 was correct...